# How to display different dates from different rows having same ID in a single ROW?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch date from different Rows based on a common column values and display it in a Single Row.

We have following table

```
Contract ID     Created_Date        
-----------------------------
1       1/2/2014    
1       2/3/2014    
1       3/3/2014    
2       4/3/2014
2       5/3/2014    
2       6/3/2014    
2       7/3/2014    
3       8/3/2014    
3       9/3/2014    
4       10/3/2014   
4       11/3/2014
5       12/3/2014   
----------------------------
```

`Created_Date` shows when a contract started and when we have new date against same `contract_id`, it means previous contract was terminated and new contract started. I want to show that when a `contract` was started and ended in single row.

Following are expected results

```
Contract ID     Created_Date        Terminated_Date     
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       1/2/2014            2/3/2014
1       2/3/2014            3/3/2014
1       3/3/2014            NULL
2       4/3/2014            5/3/2014
2       5/3/2014            6/3/2014
2       6/3/2014            7/3/2014
2       7/3/2014            NULL
3       8/3/2014            9/3/2014
3       9/3/2014            NULL
4       10/3/2014           11/3/2014
4       11/3/2014           NULL
5       12/3/2014           NULL

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

`NULL values` is there because that specific contract have no further `created_dates` so it is not terminated yet.

Comment: MySQL or sql-server?

Comment: This is an unlikely data set. Are you sure that it's properly representative of the actual problem?

Comment: It is MySQL @Jens

Comment: May be But I have this kind of data in hand @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(Contract_ID INT NOT NULL
,Created_Date DATE PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,STR_TO_DATE('1/2/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),  
(1,STR_TO_DATE('2/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')), 
(1,STR_TO_DATE('3/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(2,STR_TO_DATE('4/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),
(2,STR_TO_DATE('5/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(2,STR_TO_DATE('6/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(2,STR_TO_DATE('7/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(3,STR_TO_DATE('8/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(3,STR_TO_DATE('9/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),    
(4,STR_TO_DATE('10/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),   
(4,STR_TO_DATE('11/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y')),
(5,STR_TO_DATE('12/3/2014','%d/%m/%Y'));
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.* 
     , MIN(b.created_date) next
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.contract_id = a.contract_id
   AND b.created_date > a.created_date
 GROUP
    BY a.contract_id
     , a.created_date;

| Contract_ID | Created_Date | next       |
| ----------- | ------------ | ---------- |
| 1           | 2014-02-01   | 2014-03-02 |
| 1           | 2014-03-02   | 2014-03-03 |
| 1           | 2014-03-03   |            |
| 2           | 2014-03-04   | 2014-03-05 |
| 2           | 2014-03-05   | 2014-03-06 |
| 2           | 2014-03-06   | 2014-03-07 |
| 2           | 2014-03-07   |            |
| 3           | 2014-03-08   | 2014-03-09 |
| 3           | 2014-03-09   |            |
| 4           | 2014-03-10   | 2014-03-11 |
| 4           | 2014-03-11   |            |
| 5           | 2014-03-12   |            |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQtqaFgfita1dPPo64C4YW/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea

```
select
  a.ContractID,
  a.Created_Date,
  b.Terminated_Date
from
  (
    select
      ContractID,
      Created_Date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY
          Created_Date ASC
      ) as rownum
    from
      Table1
  ) a
  Left Join (
    select
      ContractID,
      Created_Date as Terminated_Date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY
          Created_Date ASC
      ) as rownum
    from
      Table1
  ) b on b.ContractID= a.ContractID
  and b.rownum = a.rownum + 1
```